# How to mathematically express permittivity as a function of frequency

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, boundary-conditions, dielectric

I am a amateur physics student. I am modelling the wave propagation of an EM wave at different frequencies through water placed between two acrylic rectangular materials using [COMSOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMSOL_Multiphysics). But since the frequency varies the permittivity of the substance changes accordingly. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Can you point to a specific difficulty you're having?

Comment: Are you asking for data on the value of the permittivity as a function of frequency and temperature? If so the data [is a mere Google away](https://www.google.com/search?q=water+permittivity+frequency). Or are you asking for some technical detail of how to incorporate the change in COMSOL?

Comment: @JohnRennie yeah i need permittivity as a function of frequency to incorporate it in the comsol. I am trying to simulate the response of a system in which water is a dielectric at various frequencies. And later I also want to simulate the same with NaCl system. To be more clear imagine a drop of water is squeezed between two acrylic glasses and then subjected to radio frequencies to assess the dielectric constants.

Comment: There's isn't a simple analytic expression for the permittivity. You'll need to take the experimental data and fit some convenient function to it. Then use that function in your model.

Comment: @psitae I have narrated my problem above.... To be a bit little more precise... The permittivity varies accordingly with the change in frequency and temperature. So I want to estimate the transmittance, absorbance and reflectance of a sample when exposed to various frequencies of electromagnetic wave.

Comment: @JohnRennie thank you.... One small thing which i need to clarify.... Provided with standard temperature and pressure conditions, can you help me in knowing if permittivity as a function of frequency is monotonously decreasing or increasing

Comment: @shiva you'll need to look up the experimental data to answer that. Offhand I don't know the answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie... thank you.... also i am a newbie to comsol.... can you guide me through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you know the actual dielectric constant $\epsilon_r=\epsilon_r\left(\nu\right)$, where $\nu$ is the frequency, i.e. provided you have a CSV file with two columns (or equivalent), you simply create a function (Model->Global Definitions->Functions->Piecewise) using your CSV file. You can then use this function as the input for your water material. It is not difficult, but requires some practice. Maybe there are Youtube videos available.

Which version of COMSOL?

Comment: Thank you @Cryo ..... i am glad that you did answer. I am using comsol 4.4. The setup looks like three layers are placed in rectangular form in which the top and bottom layers are acrylic. The middle layer is Water. I need to observe the plot for power distributed above third later under the physics of EM Waves and study of Frequency domain. I have elaborated about my problem more in the comments session above.

Comment: COMSOL will require an expression for permittivity of some sort. Either experimental data or an equation. I was under impression that this data is available and the only thing you need is a way of feeding it into COMSOL. Is this correct? What format is the data in?

Comment: I am sorry, cuz i don't have data... I am actually doing some work to acquire the data. I am working on predicting the concentration of a solution based on the permittivity and/or dielectric properties. So the tie up is I even don't know the permitivitty as a function of concentration of a solution. I did some work and acquired some values which i am not confident enough. But thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. You start by saying you don't have it - then find it (google). If you do have the data, can you tell me what format is it in?

frequency: 1Hz, 2Hz, 3Hz, ....

dielctric constant: 1+i, 2+0.5i, ...

Etc...? In principle you could break the task in two. Use arbitrary data (just make it up) to understand how to feed it into COMSOL, then go find the real data.

Comment: It seems you may have accidentally posted this as an answer while trying to reply to shiva's comment on your other answer.

Comment: I initially wanted to make a table, but the comment formatting messed it up, so I went for another answer